# Tabs active effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have six different tabs and on-click of any off the tabs it should get highlighted. But my tab is failing, I don't know where I am going wrong. Please let me know my mistake.

script:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('tabCtrl',function() {           
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function (tabId) {
        this.tab = tabId;
    };

this.isSet = function (tabId) {
    return this.tab === tabId;
    };
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VH1iGHS17sM4CDanEQCY?p=preview

Above one is the plunker which I have created. Please look over it.

Comment: Your plunker is working, you just missed the style stuff for the active tab.
https://plnkr.co/edit/YCBrR7ES78l2vJRniZfq?p=preview

Comment: thanks for correcting me @felixmosh

Answer (score 0):

Your code to select a tab is perfectly fine, i.e. when you click on a tab, the binding `ng-click="tab.setTab(2)"` does execute and set that tab as active.

`ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"` is also setting the CSS class `active` on the clicked tab.

However, you might be unable to view the problem because you have not added any CSS styles that hightlight the selected tab.

For example, if you add the following CSS, you will be able to see the selected tab highlighted with lightblue background:

```
.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Here's the updated code: https://plnkr.co/edit/CBmwvv6VEbfp8vbbndtp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @nisarg shah

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You just need to define your CSS for 'active' tabs. Try something like this:

```
.active {
    background: blue;
    color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

Updated [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/b3PaKC3rNlxPvhOxQYkP?p=preview).